# OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer not rendering but new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS does

Tags: openlayers-2, mapserver

I got the following code:

```
var layern2 = new OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer("Tech",
                "ServerPathTo_mapserv.exe",
                {
                    map: "ServerPathTo_My.map"
                },
                {
                    isBaseLayer: false,
                    layer: "Layer1",
                    version: "1.1.1",
                    transparent: "true",
                    visibility: true
                });
```

That does not render a non transparent layer without images (all titles are rendered with a missing image icon on the upper left corner)...

But the following Code does render everything in the correct way:

```
var layern2 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Tech",
                  "ServerPathTo_mapserv.exe?map=ServerPathTo_My.map&REQUEST=getmap&VERSION=1.1.1&LAYERS=Layer1&FORMAT=PNG", { layers: 'Layer1', TRANSPARENT: 'TRUE' });
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct code is:

```
var layern2 = new OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer("Tech",
"ServerPathTo_mapserv.exe",
{
     map: "ServerPathTo_My.map",
     layer: "Layer1",
     version: "1.1.1",
     transparent: "true"
},
{
     isBaseLayer: false,
     visibility: true
});
```